# Spam/ham classification

Tags: machine-learning, python, text-classification, lime

I am exploring the use of lime for spam/ham categorisation.
specifically I have a data frame having list of messages.
I would need to identify which messages are spam and which ones are ham by using a set of words (100).
I would need to find to test the accuracy of the model. I found some articles on towardsdatasciene and medium that helped me a bit, but I would need a really small example on what I would need (already labelled messages? If yes, I should manually label them first, or should I use some algorithm to label them as spam/ham? How could I predict a new message?...).

Any explanation and comment would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: By LIME, do you refer to https://github.com/marcotcr/lime?

Comment: Yes, but I would be more interested in understanding how to build the dataset  that I need, how to get labels For example